# Invoke delegate in Global.asax.cs?

Tags: c#, wcf, delegates

I have a delegate declared in Global.asax.cs:

```
 Delegate List<NewData> DelegateNewData();
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
     DelegateNewData delNewData;

}
```

in application_start:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      delNewData = new DelegateNewData(GetList.GetNewData);
  }
```

Procedure:

```
private void getData()
 {
    //i need to invoke the delegate here like  
     this.invoke(delNewData,new object[]{});
 }
```

But using `this` is not working because it is uses only controls and forms.

My question is:

How to invoke the delegate in `private void getData()` procedure;?

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: `this` is not related in any way to controls and forms. Every object has `this` pointing to itself and since this is not a static method there is a `this`z What is the actual problem? Are there errors? Always include them.

Comment: Thanks @SamiKuhmonen i know that, but what i mean is on that particular when using delegate to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke it like you call a function:

```
private void getData() {
  delNewData();
}
```

Comment: Need some question.. how about if delegate procedure has a parameter? Is it ok if i do it like `delNewData(param1);`?

Comment: Yup, exactly. Like you call any standard function. Of course, your delegate signature mush accept a parameter of the same type.

Comment: Thanks @RacilHilan.